Trying to delete last two commits from git
I am trying to delete last two commits (fixed calculations , fixed) and want to add these changes in 3rd commit(Contract Functions) with amend


You would need to do an interactive rebase back the commit before Contract Functions. Then just squash those two commits as Fixups.


I am trying to delete last two commits (fixed calculations , fixed)

There isn't really a direct concept of 'deleting' commits in Git, although I'm going to assume that by 'delete' the commits you mean "remove them from the branch history". You can reset the HEAD of your branch to the Contract Functions commit, effectively removing the fixed and Fixed calculations commits from your branch history. However note this is a destructive operation and if you've shared your branch with others then this may not be an option.
The syntax to do this would be git reset --hard <Commit hash of the Contract Functions commit>.

and want to add these changes in 3rd commit(Contract Functions) with amend

This part of your question confused me a little, are you saying you want the changes from your fixed and Fixed calculations commits to be incorporated into the Contract Functions commit? If so then I'd recommend interactively rebasing, which allows you to mark the fixed and Fixed calculations commits as fixup commits, where they will both be squashed (incorporated) into the Contract function commit. For more reading on this see: Git Tools - Rewriting History, but the command you'll want to use to kick things off is git rebase -i HEAD~3.
Note in both cases you will re-write the history of the branch which is a destructive operation, and this violates the so-called 'Golden rule' of Git rebasing.
